# How to go back default settings of eth0

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, ip, ifconfig

When my system starts, eth0 was not assigned with any of the IP addresses. Its looks like below

```
root@etn-cgtqmx6:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:xxxx  Metric:1
          RX packets:xxx errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:xxx
          RX bytes:54167 (52.8 KiB)  TX bytes:42 (42.0 B)
```

after assigning ip address 198.168.20.10 the configuration looks like below

```
root@etn-cgtqmx6:~# ifconfig eth0 192.168.20.10
root@etn-cgtqmx6:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x
          inet addr:192.168.20.10  Bcast:192.168.20.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:xxxx  Metric:1
          RX packets:xxx errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:xxx
          RX bytes:54167 (52.8 KiB)  TX bytes:42 (42.0 B)
```

My doubt is after assigning an ip address, how can we go back to the default settings?

Answer (score 1):

> $ ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0

Assigning a value of 0.0.0.0 will clear the current ip association.

Based on your distro, you can also try to restart the network service by using commands like

> $ systemctl restart systemd-networkd
>
> $ /etc/rc.d/init.d/network restart
>
> $ service networking restart

Comment: why should we restart the service?

Comment: Restarting the service reinitializes the network devices with the settings as stored in the configuration files, which in your case may be default.